# How to duplicate a C macro?

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to make a C macro (`TRAMPOLINE_BLOCK`) which takes a predefined macro constant (`TRAMPOLINE_LENGTH`) and writes that many `asm volatile` `nop` instructions. For example:

```
#ifdef __x86_64__
    #define TRAMPOLINE_LENGTH 41
    #define TRAMPOLINE_BLOCK  \
        ({ \
            asm volatile ( \
                    "nop\n" \
                    ...
            );\
        })
#else
    #define TRAMPOLINE_LENGTH ...
    #define TRAMPOLINE_BLOCK ...
#endif
```

In this case, `TRAMPOLINE_BLOCK` should have 41 `nop` instructions. I've been playing around with macro arguments and the such but haven't got it working yet. How would I go about writing such a macro?

Answer (score 1):

Doing that yourself is relatively complicated.

[P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/group__basic__list__operations.html) has a macro `P99_DUPL` that allows you to do something like you want

```
 P99_DUPL(41, TRAMPOLINE_BLOCK)
```

should do the trick. You need a C99 compliant compiler for this.